# Possible to create an alert in Netsuite for an open estimate?

Tags: estimation

We have several people who create estimates in NetSuite but are not always the people fulfilling orders. Is it possible to create an alert when making a sales order if there is an open estimate associated with that prospect/customer?

Looking for any help how to handle this so we do not have numerous open estimates that may have actually converted to sales orders

Answer (score 0):

You can write a client script with saveRecord function and deploy it on sales order. And you can create the customer record saved search in script and check for related records with type estimate. If it is having more than zero results you can put an validation with alert in same script.

I hope , you will get this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I will pass this info on to our IT team and reach back with any questions.